# smartmontols unknown attributes for scandisk SSD

Tags: lubuntu, ssd, 19.10

I make a long test for my SSD (scandisks), but I get some unknown Unknown_Attributes.

```
sudo lshw -c disk
  *-disk:0                  
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SanDisk SDSSDA12
       physical id: 0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 30RL
       serial: 173003A01451
       size: 111GiB (120GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=6e43b068
```

[smartctl output](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/mr47RV59Ts/)

I downloaded [drivedb.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/smartmontools/master) in the hope this will fix my Problem.

```
apt-cache policy smartmontools 
smartmontools:
  Installiert:           7.0-0ubuntu1
  Installationskandidat: 7.0-0ubuntu1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 7.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I found this [ticket](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/337) But I'm not sure if I can make the changes in my drivedb.h without destroying something.

Comment: If you actually found the meanings of those 160s attributes, you should file a bug to get them into the repository's drive.h.  Looks like you may just add the new attributes to the existing list (after the 162 attribute, which is still unknnown but has added the vendor name.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/715), [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/463?cversion=2&cnum_hist=4)